# Access jquery annotator notes

Tags: javascript, jquery, annotations

I am using [jquery annotator](https://github.com/okfn/annotator) to annotate and take notes on a site. I have the need to add additional style if the user has added a note.

I am trying to create a small plugin that will add a class to the highlight if a note exists for that highlight, but I can't seem to get access to the note from within my plugin.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

Here's my plugin so far, just a start to be able to look into the annotator object. I can't find anything in the log of the annotator object that gives me information about the notes attached to a highlight.

```
Annotator.Plugin.Milestone = function(element) {
   var milestoneAnnotator = {
        pluginInit: function() {
            console.log(this.annotator);
        }
    };

    return milestoneAnnotator;
}
```

Comment: Could you show a snippet of your code? Or tell us how you're hooking into the Annotator API? For example, in your plugin, are you subscribing to Annotator events?

Comment: @maxenglander My plugin isn't doing anything as of yet, I'm just trying to find any information about notes that I can, but there doesn't appear to be anything in the annotator object, or at least I don't see anything. See above. I shouldn't need to hook into events, plus I'll need to add a class for highlights with notes on page load, so events wouldn't help me there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subscribing to the `annotationsLoaded` event will give you access to all of your stored annotations when they are loaded in to the DOM, according to the [Annotator readme](https://github.com/okfn/annotator).

Now, as for adding a class to a highlight, I assume you mean a CSS class? Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/gist/jquery/1.7.2/3181343/) of adding a CSS class to all annotations when they are loaded in to the DOM.

To only add a class to annotations with notes, you would just check for the `text` property on the annotation.